# SVG element SET not working accessKey()

Tags: html, browser, svg, svg-animate

Easy example, change color text from blue to red:

```
<svg width="500" height="500">

   <text id="TextElement" x="20" y="200"
   style="font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:13; stroke:blue" >
   Now you see me!
   <set attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" to="red" begin="3s" fill="freeze"/>
   </text>

</svg>
```

when **begin="3s"** work fine but

```
<svg width="500" height="500">

   <text id="TextElement" x="20" y="200"
   style="font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:13; stroke:blue" >
   Now you see me!
   <set attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" to="red" begin="accessKey(a)" fill="freeze"/>
   </text>

</svg>
```

when **begin="accessKey(a)"** it do not working.

Browser: Google Chrome  35.0.1916.153 (Official Build 274914).

P.S. I need accessKey() **only in SVG**, not JavaScript or other...

**UPDATE:** in FireFox v17 and v31, accessKey(a) work fine

Comment: Confirmed broken in Chrome with: https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/3294/begin-5-accesskey.svg

Comment: As my feeling accessKey disabled specially for security reason, like SVG keylogger, detail http://lcx.cc/?i=3935